# C++: "Exception thrown: read access violation." when assigning a vector to the other

Tags: c++, stl

I created a class called Bounds3 which has a vector as its member variable. The error happens when assigning one Bounds3's instance to the other. I have solved this problem by copying vector using a loop of `push_back` instead of using a `=` operator, but I still want to know why this error happens when assigning the vector using `=` operator.

The Bounds3 class:

```
template <typename T>
class Bounds3 {
  public:
    ... //public methods

    ... //other public member variables
    std::vector<int> offsets;// the vector
}
```

The place where the error happens:

```
int BVHAccel::flattenBVHTree(BVHBuildNode *node, int *offset) {
    LinearBVHNode *linearNode = &nodes[*offset];
    linearNode->bounds = node->bounds;// Error happens here: these two "bounds" are instances of Bounds3 class, which belong to the other 2 classes: BVHBuildNode and LinearBVHNode respectively.
    ...
}
```

When the error first happened, I checked the call stack and thought it may because I didn't write a overloaded "operator=" function to do the customized assignment so I overloaded the = operator using following code.

So I wrote such a overloaded = operator function:

```
Bounds3<T> &operator=(const Bounds3<T> &b) {
    ...// copy other member variables
    offsets = b.offsets; // error happens here
    return *this;
}
```

The error is still there and it may because the default behavior when there is no such overloaded operator using `=` to assign the vector. Thus, I modified the function:

```
Bounds3<T> &operator=(const Bounds3<T> &b) {
    ...// copy other member variables
    for (auto &p : b.offsets) 
        offsets.push_back(p);
    return *this;
}
```

Then, the error disappeared.

I have tried my best to check similar questions and found no (to the best of my knowledge) exactly same questions. I know it happens when accessing uninitialized memory space like accessing a block of uninitialized memory pointed by some pointers or accessing an element of an empty vector using index, but how could the `=` operator fails to assign memory space for the vector? (I find a very similar question here ["Exception thrown: read access violation" when I'm trying to assign a vector to vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59587537/9083790), but it may because this guy's vector stores shared_ptr while my vector is just a vector of integers.)

BTW, according to my design, this vector could be empty in a Bounds3 instance. In particular, when the assignment showed above happened, the `offsets` in `node->bounds` are empty. Is this the reason for the problem?

I am not familiar with the underlying logistics of C++ STLs. Hope you could give me some hints. Thanks for your help in advance!

---

**Edit:**

I am sorry I'm not able to provide the all the code for the reproducing purpose since it involves too many code. What I was doing is to modify a class called `Bounds3` (line 749) in  [a file of a open-source project](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/aaa552a4b9cbf9dccb71450f47b268e0ed6370e2/src/core/geometry.h#L749). After I add a vector member to this `Bounds3` class, the error happens [in this file (line 640)](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/aaa552a4b9cbf9dccb71450f47b268e0ed6370e2/src/accelerators/bvh.cpp#L640).

Comment: More likely than not, the issue is that `*offset` is pointing beyond the end of `nodes`.

Comment: You haven't emptied the `offsets` before pushing new elements. Are you sure it is empty?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Simplify your code as much as you can while still producing the error; the bug will probably become obvious to you along the way, and otherwise you will arrive at a very simple example that you can post here.

Comment: @BillLynch Maybe not... I checked the call stack, the last call before entering the underlying std::vector code is the "Bounds3<T> &operator=(const Bounds3<T> &b)" function. Also, that `LinearBVHNode *linearNode = &nodes[*offset];` line gave no error when debugging it.

Comment: @Hiroki That `Bounds3` class needs no overloaded copy constructor or assignment operator.  The only member variable is a `Point3<T>`, and depending what `T` is, is safely copyable and assignable right out-of-the-box.  By adding functions, all you're doing is masking the error, not fixing it.  I suggest you remove all of that code that does nothing, reproduce the error, and really fix the error.

Comment: @Beta Just provide more background on the code. Hope it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for your advice. The original code (i.e., Bounds3 class without a vector member) works fine, but I would like to extend this class so I added a new vector member in that class and it fails to execute. What is the proper way to extend it? PS: I need to store a sequence of T variables in each instance of this class.

Comment: @Hiroki -- A `std::vector` of what type?  `std::vector<int>`?  `std::vector<char>`?  If the type is safely copyable, then maybe the original code already had a hidden bug that was never exposed.  Adding a vector of a safely copyable type shouldn't give any issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Since Bounds3 is a template with T as its type parameter, I want to store a `std::vector<Point2<T>>` in each instance. Update: thanks for your advice, I will look into other parts of the code to find the cause.

Comment: What is the type `T` in your real code that causes the issue?  That's what I am trying to pin down.  Also, why not just add that member, and make no other changes -- don't add your own code to "handle" this, nothing.  If the program doesn't work properly by just adding that member, then the code was broken prior to you changing anything, or the original code requires the classes being used to be trivially-copyable, and adding `std::vector` broke that contract.  It's that simple.

Comment: Have you used valgrind or the address sanitizer?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just did what you said by adding that member only and the same error happened. The `T` is `float` in this case. I guess it is because the second reason you mentioned. I will look into it. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

After I investigate into the details of this project, I found the reason was that the `vector<int> offsets` in that `Bounds3` class was not initialized at all when the assignment happend.

Here is what happened: this project self-defined an `AllocAligned` function to allocate space for the `nodes` array in the code, i.e., the array which the `LinearBVHNode *linearNode` points to. This `AllocAligned` function then uses the `_aligned_malloc` function to allocate memory, which does not initialize the vector in `linearNode->bounds` at all, and that's why the assignment between two bounds failed.

BTW, in terms of the reason for the problem, this question may be marked as a duplicated question.  [Here is the similar question I found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757583/9083790)